# Azure Monitor Workbook - run ARM query per each resource

Tags: azure, azure-monitor-workbooks

I'm looking into Azure Workbooks now, and I'm wondering if the below is actually even possible.

**Scenario**

1. List all function apps under Subscription / Resource Group scope.

This step is done - simple Azure Resource Graph query with parameters does the job.

2. Execute Azure Resource Manager action against **each** Function App that was returned as a part of Query in Step1.

Specifically, I'm interested in *detectors/functionExecutionErrors* ARM API - and return a parsed result out of it. When doing that for hardcoded resource, I can get the results I need. Using the following JSON Path `$.properties.dataset[0].table.rows[0][1]` I get back the summary: *All running functions in healthy state with execution failure rate less than 0.1%.*

I realize this might either be undoable in Workbooks or something trivial that I missed - it would be easiest if I could just run 'calculated columns' when rendering outputs. So, the summarizing question is:

How, if possible, can I combine Azure Resource Graph query with Azure Resource Manager DataSource, where Azure Resource Manager query runs per each returned Graph resource and display them as table in form: "Resource ID | ARM api results".

I think I have achieved closest result to this by marking Resource Graph Query output as parameter (id -> FunctionAppId) and referencing that in ARM query as `/{FunctionAppId}/detectors/functionExecutionErrors` - this works fine as long as **only one** resource is selected, but there are two obstacles: I want to execute against all query results regardless if they are selected, and I need Azure Resource Manager understand it needs to loop resources - not concatenate them (as seen in `invoke` HTTP call from F12 dev tools, the resource names are just joined together).

Hopefully there's someone out there who could help out with this. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Workbooks doesn't currently have an ability to run the ARM data source against many resources, though it is on our backlog and are actively investigating a way to run *any* datasource for a set of values and merge the results togther.

The general workaround is to do as stated, either use a parameter so select a resource and run that one query for the selected item, or do similar with something like a query step with grid, and have selection of the grid output a parameter used as input to the ARM query step.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also new to Workbooks and I think creating a parameter first with the functionId is best. I do the same ;)
With multiple functions the parameter will have them all. You can use `split()` to get an array and then loop.
Will that work for you?

Can you share your solution if you managed to solve this differently?
`cloudsma.com` is a resource I use a lot to understand the queries and options better. Like this one: https://www.cloudsma.com/2022/03/azure-monitor-alert-reports